# Many Vue projects, one node_modules

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm making a new project. I have one server application (Node, Express, Mongo) and I'm having two client application (both are VueJS). I want this structure (I want only one `node_modules` directory):

```
- client
--- admin (vue project)
--- page (vue project)
- server
--- server.js
- node_modules
- package.json
```

I server app works fine, but I have problems with VueJS. I created new project with `vue-cli`, remove `node_modules` and `package.json`. All dependencies I have in main `node_modules`. I had error:

```
These relative modules were not found:

* ./build/dev-client in multi ./build/dev-client ./src/main.js
* ./src/main.js in multi ./build/dev-client ./src/main.js
```

But I resolved this by changing paths in `webpack.base.conf` from this:

```
entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
```

to this:

```
entry: {
    app: './client/admin/src/main.js'
  },
```

and in `webpack.dev.conf` from this:

```
Object.keys(baseWebpackConfig.entry).forEach(function (name) {
  baseWebpackConfig.entry[name] = ['./build/dev-client'].concat(baseWebpackConfig.entry[name])
})
```

to this:

```
Object.keys(baseWebpackConfig.entry).forEach(function (name) {
  baseWebpackConfig.entry[name] = ['./client/admin/build/dev-client'].concat(baseWebpackConfig.entry[name])
})
```

Project is now running but now I have this error:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                 

 error
```

and I don't know how to fix it. Please help